# Issues while Trying to setup elk version 8.9.1 using docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I'm trying to setup elk stack in docker and I'm facing few issues.

1. by using docker compose - I'm not able to login into kibana dashboard, as I'm not able to get the passcode.
2. I tried to setup elastic search, kibana and logstash seperately ( without docker compose) .. I'm not able to setup logstash ..
3. objective is to set up elk in docker, and link a small service, and to get the logs of the service.

Any help this will be appreciated.

Thanks

Expectations: to get the logs from a service into elk and learn it.

Comment: Did you follow the official guide? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/docker.html#docker-generate
It is nice to show the error when you could not setup logstash

Comment: yes, i did try creating a new token for kibana, after entering the newly generated token, it asks for 6digit verificaion code, which i could not get if i use docker-compose. If i use kibana container seperately, and add the token, the 6digit code will be shown on terminal

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're actually writing any of your own code, just trying to deploy a pre-built log-management solution.  Another site like [devops.se] or [sf] might be a more appropriate place for questions like this.

Comment: by using .env file we can solve it.. got it. I will sure check the above sites for further queries . Thank you all